# How could this be considered performant code?

Tags: java, performance

I came across this (Java) code yesterday and can't figure out why someone would have done this in any language.

In what scenario, language, paranoid delusion would "removing" values from an ArrayList like this improve performance? Try to avoid getting dragged in to the general design of the worker. I know it's bad and should be different, but I'm trying to understand if there is a reason for writing a 'remove' method this way.

Some points of clarification:

- tradeIdList contains no duplicate values
- It is populated in the constructor and never read until the worker has finished.
- The class reading this result simply prints the contents to a log file.

  public class TradeIdWorker implements Runnable{
      private List tradeIdList = new ArrayList();
      ....

  ```
  public void run(){
      // Copy the tradeIdList to an array (No I do not know why)
      for (int tradeId : tradeIdArray){
          ....
          // Once processed, remove it
          removeProcessedTradeId(tradeId);
  }

  /**
   * Set Trade id to zero (for performance)
   */
  private void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId) {
      for (int index = 0; index < tradeIdList.size(); index++) {
          if (tradeIdList.get(index).intValue() == tradeId) {
              tradeIdList.set(index, 0);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

To try and understand why I've added a real world use case from the system. The arraylist of tradeIds never contains duplicates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    testNormalRemove();
    testPerformantRemove();
}

private static void testNormalRemove() {
    ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        aList.add(i);
    }

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i += 1000) {
        aList.remove((Object) i);
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Normal Took: " + (end - start)); // 1700ms
}

private static void testPerformantRemove() {
    ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        aList.add(i);
    }

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i += 1000) {
        for (int index = 0; index < aList.size(); index++) {
            if (aList.get(index).intValue() == i) {
                aList.set(index, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Performant Took: " + (end - start)); // 4800ms
}
```

Comment: I can imagine lots of reasons why this could make sense, performance is only one of them, so maybe the comment is just incomplete?

Comment: Can you elaborate why it makes sense? In practice, the code above iterates over the entire arraylist, rather than failing fast when it encounters an element to remove.

Comment: "Fail fast" is an option when tradeIdList contains each value only once (which was not obvious from the initial code snippet). Moreover, "fail fast" is not contrary to using 0 for indicating deleted elements.  Another reason might be to avoid invalidation of existing indexes referring into the "tradeIdList" (in code outside the snippet, either). There could be code relying on the fact "tradeIdList" never decreases its size. And so on. One has to review the class in full for a judgement call.

Comment: Yes, understood. I'll update the question to clarify those points.

Comment: When you start posting the code of the whole class, your question will most probably become "off topic" for Programmers.SE, but may be suitable for "codereview.stackexchange" ;-)

Comment: @JayMee That's a very useful comment though.

Comment: @DocBrown - I should have structured the initial question more carefully. I was specifically trying to identify scenarios in which looping and setting zeros would be a useful case. Pete Kirkham has answered it well.

Comment: @beirtipol you're not doing the same things though - the remove example finds the first element to remove and removes it, the zero example iterates through all elements and zeroes the single one that matches. If you wanted to compare alike, you'd break out of the loop after you found the element to zero. Effectively you're comparing Pete's 'zero all' with 'remove once'

Comment: @beirtipol: Have you looked at the history of the code in question? Perhaps it was the right (and a performant) way of doing it when originally written, but have subsequent edits removed the benefits that the code originally had.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Unfortunately it's a codebase with lost history, i.e. the repo was switched from an old SVN a few years back. Ideally, yes, the history would give some insight.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - that is the point of the question. The code that I queried about does not break after finding the matching element!

Comment: Ahah, I see - poor code that works slower with a comment that says "this is faster". They got it wrong, pure and simple. Phil's answer explains what they were thinking, they just implemented it badly. This is a situation where a comment is correct and the code has a bug. Comments are good after all. If you fixed the bug by putting the break in, it would perform better.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking:) It's good to understand the possible benefits of this approach, but I didn't explain it well enough in my original question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing an element in an ArrayList requires shifting all the remaining elements with a higher index down one. Marking an element with a zero does not.

So if N is the number of elements in tradeIdList and M is the number of elements in tradeIdArray, this approach is O(M × N) whereas actually removing the elements on each iteration of M is O(M×N²).

Typically there would be a final pass to remove all the blanked values, which would be O(N) and so not increase the complexity.

This applies for the general case - the code iterates over all of the array list, zeroing any occurrence of the id. If you can assume that there is only one occurrence, then there will not be a difference in the times.

In the following, the tests compare a set of inputs with repeats.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Programmers312172 {
    public static void main (String ... args) {
        Worker[] workers = {new TradeIdWorker(), new RemoveWorker(), new ZeroOnceWorker(), new RemoveOnceWorker()};

        for (int run = 0; run < 10; ++run) {
            for ( Worker worker : workers )
                worker.prepare();

            for ( Worker worker : workers ) {
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                worker.run();
                long end = System.nanoTime();
                System.out.printf("%-24s  %12dns\n", worker, end-start);
            }
        }
    }

    static int[] prepareInputs (List<Integer> tradeIdList) {
        Random  r = new Random(0);
        int[]   tradeIdArray = new int[1000];

        for(int i=0; i < 100000; ++i)
            tradeIdList.add(r.nextInt(2000));

        for(int i=0; i < 1000; ++i)
            tradeIdArray[i] = i;

        return tradeIdArray;
    }

    public abstract static class Worker {
        protected List<Integer> tradeIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private int[] tradeIdArray;

        public void prepare() {
            tradeIdArray = prepareInputs(tradeIdList);
        }

        public void run(){
            for (int tradeId : tradeIdArray)
                removeProcessedTradeId(tradeId);
        }

        protected abstract void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId);
    }            

    public static class TradeIdWorker extends Worker {
        @Override
        protected void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId) {
            for (int index = 0; index < tradeIdList.size(); index++) {
                if (tradeIdList.get(index).intValue() == tradeId) {
                    tradeIdList.set(index, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() { return "zero all"; }
    }            
    public static class ZeroOnceWorker extends Worker {
        @Override
        protected void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId) {
            for (int index = 0; index < tradeIdList.size(); index++) {
                if (tradeIdList.get(index).intValue() == tradeId) {
                    tradeIdList.set(index, 0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() { return "zero once"; }
    }            
    public static class RemoveWorker extends Worker {
        protected void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId) {
            Integer toRemove = tradeId;
            while(tradeIdList.remove(toRemove));
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() { return "remove all"; }
    }            
    public static class RemoveOnceWorker extends Worker {
        protected void removeProcessedTradeId(int tradeId) {
            tradeIdList.remove((Integer)tradeId);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() { return "remove once"; }
    }
}
```

This gives values such as

```
zero all                    1136905192ns
remove all                 13162226491ns
zero once                      6587605ns
remove once                   70135769ns
```

Other data will change the relationships, but typically there will be similar speed increases. As the value will typically be hit in the first 2% of the elements, zero once can stop after iterating over 2% of the list, but remove once has to move the remaining 98% down so has to iterate over all the list. You could probably also come up with inputs that show no improvement ( e.g. single occurrence, remove in reverse order from the end ), but in general zeroing will be better.

Comment: I've done a performance test on this with JDK6. With an ArrayList of 1,000,000 elements, performing 1,000 "removes" by setting the value to 0 takes 5.4s. Just calling aList.remove() takes 2.1s.

Comment: @beirtipol add your test code to your post. Note that the effect of remove(Object) and the code in your post is different - if you can assume that there is only one occurrance in the list you also can add a `break;` after `tradeIdList.set(index, 0); `

Comment: Have added test case. It certainly makes sense to break out of the loop. The point is that it doesn't and I'm still wondering how it can be 'performant'.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - it shows a scenario where this code could be more useful, but only if used with 'break'.

Comment: Use Objective-C. Removing the first element of an NSMutableArray is O (1). Same as inserting an element at the start of an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @gnasher729  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1416616-removeobject says 'all elements beyond index are moved by subtracting 1 from their index' which is O(N). The *last* element has a special operation which will be O(1), but not the first.